# How can you inherit 2 smart contracts which are using ERC20 and ERC721 into a third contract named thirdContract.sol

Tags: ethereum, solidity

There are 3 smart contracts:

1. First smart contract erctoken.sol TypeError: Derived contract must override function "_mint". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
   --> IdjotNft.sol:10:1:
   |
   10 | contract idjotNft is ERC721, Ownable, idjotTokenContract {
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
   Note: Definition in "ERC20":
   --> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:259:5:
   |
   259 | function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
   Note: Definition in "ERC721":
   --> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:286:5:
   |
   286 | function _mint(address to, uint256 tokenId) internal virtual {
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

TypeError: Derived contract must override function "_transfer". Two or more base classes define function with same name and parameter types.
--> IdjotNft.sol:10:1:
|
10 | contract idjotNft is ERC721, Ownable, idjotTokenContract {
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC20":
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:226:5:
|
226 | function _transfer(
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Definition in "ERC721":
--> @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol:355:5:
|
355 | function _transfer(
| ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

I want to inherit both the smart contracts using "is" operator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error message, it seems that you're trying to use ERC20 along ERC721, which are both implementations of different standards.

They will have implemented some functions differently such as transfer(), mint(), name(), symbol(), totalSuply(), etc... which means that they cannot be used together.

It is not best practice using them together, and your only bet to use them together would be to use their interface, such as IERC20 or IERC721 and implement them yourself in your contract.